# angular ngClass directive not getting applied

Tags: javascript, css, angular

Can some please help not sure why ngClass is not getting applied [in this code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3qhgkw)

```
[ngClass]="{'active': isActive,'can-toggle':canToggle}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member variables `isActive` and `canToggle` are wrongfully defined as types `true` and `false`. It should actually be assigned the booleans instead

```js
isActive = true;
canToggle = false;
```

Modified [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vnbswp).

Answer (score 1):

Change this :

```
isActive:true;
canToggle:false;
```

to this :

```
isActive = true;
canToggle = false;
```